# How to see if Event triggered using Ajax on Another page in Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have two aspx pages on sender.aspx i have a table in which each row contain two buttons edit and delete for that i have used ajax have a look on code

```
 $(".btnedit").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.post("ajax.aspx", { IDedit: id }, function (msg) {
                $.get("ajax.aspx", { IDedit: id }, function (data) {
                    //$('#loaddata').html(data);
                    alert(data);
                });

                alert(dt);
            });
        });

        $(".btndelete").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.post("ajax.aspx", { IDdel: id }, function (dt) {
                $.get("ajax.aspx", { IDdel: id }, function (data) {
                    // $('#loaddata').html(data);
                    alert(data);
                });
                alert(dt);
            });


        });
```

these are sending request successfully but when i used the following on ajax.aspx pageload.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(bool.Parse(Request.Form["IDedit"] )== true){
        Response.Write("btnedit clicked");
    }
    else if (bool.Parse(Request.Form["IDdelete"]) == true)
    {
        Response.Write("btn delete clicked");
    }
}
```

i didnt get any error but no response is generated. when i simply write Response.Write i got response please rectify what am i doing wrong.?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is not setting anything to `true`, yet your server is checking for `true`.  It should probably be checking for something else. If you wish to check for *existence*, do a null check, like this:

```
if(Request.Form["IDedit"]  != null){
    Response.Write("btnedit clicked");
}
else if (Request.Form["IDdelete"] != null)
{
    Response.Write("btn delete clicked");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the visual studio "debugger" and put the debug point on the function entry point(below). Use the debug option of visual studio and invoke the ajax(by going to the page and doing needful action which invokes ajax) and see where is control going(using step into).
 if(bool.Parse(Request.Form["IDedit"] )== true){

Comment: I got exception that " String was not recognized as a valid boolean" ? what should i do now to handle this exception ? any idea

Comment: For your information i just used Request.Form and parsed it into a boolean for checking if its value.